# XNode - AddAfterSelf - The parent is missing

Tags: c#, xml

The following code adds an item into an OrderedList, then via the index where it got inserted, insert the item into a likewise sorted XML list.

When reading the docs for XNode.[AddAfterSelf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself?view=net-5.0) it mentions it throws the exception, `InvalidOperationException` for `The parent is null.` Yet, when I run the following code, a null parent would throw `NullReferenceException` as expected for the commented out code. The actual `AddAfterSelf` throws `System.InvalidOperationException: The parent is missing.` Which to me indicates a null `parent` which would be the node `AddAfterSelf` would be following, yet it seems to me is an impossibility to call with a null parent elemment, or a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown before calling the method in the first place.

```
public static int AddSorted<A, B>(this A parent, B item)
    where A : IXCommon, IOrderedList<B>
    where B : IXCommon
{
        //XElement test = null;
        //test.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("test")); // gets null exception as expected
        int index = ~parent.Add(item);
        if (0 == index)
            parent.Element.AddFirst(item.Element);
        else if (index > 0)
            parent[index - 1].Element.AddAfterSelf(item.Element);
        else
            throw new AlreadyAddedException(item);
        return ~index;
}

public interface IXCommon
{
    XElement Element { get; }
}
```

Any thoughts on how I might be getting the invalid operation for null parent, when any attempt to call with a null parent in test gets `NullReferenceException`?

The full stack trace as requested:

```
interpretation of the trace file
class - method - inner method
computer - user
date
---
DirectoryVM - fsWatcher_Created - AddImage

DESKTOP2017 - Dune

10/7/2021 3:59:21 p m

System.InvalidOperationException: The parent is missing.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.AddAfterSelf(Object content)
   at SeaRisenLib2.Collections.OrderedListExtensions.AddSorted[A,B](A parent, B item) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\SeaRisenLib2\Project\Collections\OrderedListExtensions.cs:line 26
   at SeaRisen.FrameITLib.Files.Xml.Images.ImagesInfo.AddInternal[T](String fileName) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\FrameIT Freedom V2\FrameITLib\Project\Files\Xml\Images\ImagesInfo.cs:line 351
   at SeaRisen.FrameITLib.Files.Xml.Images.ImagesInfo.TryAdd[T](String name, T& info) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\FrameIT Freedom V2\FrameITLib\Project\Files\Xml\Images\ImagesInfo.cs:line 325
   at SeaRisen.FrameITLib.Files.Xml.Images.ImagesInfo.Add[T](String name) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\FrameIT Freedom V2\FrameITLib\Project\Files\Xml\Images\ImagesInfo.cs:line 282
   at SeaRisen.FrameITLib.Files.Xml.Images.ImageInfo.Add[T](FileInfo file) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\FrameIT Freedom V2\FrameITLib\Project\Files\Xml\Images\ImageInfo.cs:line 1090
   at SeaRisen.FrameITLib.ViewModels.DirectoryVM.fsWatcher_Created(FileInfo fileIN) in D:\JDisk\Documents\CSharp\SeaRisen\FrameIT Freedom V2\FrameITLib\Project\ViewModels\DirectoryVM.cs:line 103
The parent is missing.
```

Comment: 1) Can you share a [mcve]?  Or at the minimum the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  2) Are you sure you're not trying to add multiple roots, which would result in malformed XML according to the [XML standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)?  3) Is there any chance you are attempting to modify a list of child nodes in place?

Comment: @dbc I write all non-handled exceptions to file, so that part is easy. A reproducible example, I wish, but I could try to break it in the same way with a test project. The multiple roots shouldn't be an issue, as `parent[N]` returns a child node of the current parent node, but it's a good question. Not sure what you mean by (3), that might be exactly what I'm doing, inserting a node into a list of nodes. So why would that be bad?

Comment: *So why would that be bad?* - it might be bad because, when you add a node to a parent node **only if the added node already has a parent**, it is cloned.  See the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,ebe5a528ef86d033) for confirmation.  If you are not accounting for that, you may get confused about your list contents, leading your search and sort algorithm awry.

Comment: @dbc I think you got me headed in the right direction. Apparently (I've yet to find where in my code this is happening) I have items in my list that aren't in my xml file, so their element's don't have a parent, and hence when I try to do `element.AddAfterSelf` of an element that has no parent, the exception is thrown.